# Why do I get an error but I still get the correct output, does anyone have a solution?

Tags: python

How would make my variables suitable for arithmetic operations because I can't do addition can someone help me!

```py
 import csv
 counter = 0
 sum = 0
 with open('sales_data_sample (3).csv','r') as csv_file:
 csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
 next(csv_reader)
 for  ((lines)) in csv_reader:
     print(lines[1])
     counter = counter + 1
     sum += lines
 avg = int(counter)/int(sum)
 print(avg) #30
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:PycharmProjects\Excel_lab8\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    sum += lines
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
30 (is the answer)
    
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome. The error is caused because you can't do a add operation between a integer an a list. Can you explain what you tried to do in the line `sum += lines` or in this program in general, so we will know how to help you.

Comment: I don’t think anyone can give you a clearer answer than the error message. It says you can’t add an `int` and a `list`. It also shows a line number in the code. What else do you need to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `lines` is a list of items.  Did you mean to write `sum += lines[1]`, since you looked at `lines[1]` a few lines earlier?

And you shouldn't name a variable `sum`.